# How to add UNIQUE AUTO_INCREMENT FIRST id column

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, sequel

I would like a database migration that is basically the following SQL:

```
ALTER TABLE `myTable` ADD COLUMN `id` INT AUTO_INCREMENT UNIQUE FIRST;
```

Is there a Sequel migration that does exactly this? I have gotten pretty close with the following, but it doesn't seem to be exactly what I want:

```
Sequel.migration do
  change do
    alter_table :my_table do
      add_column :id, Bignum, null: false, unique: true
    end
  end
end
```

Specifically, it seems to be missing auto-increment and won't be the first column.

Comment: Why does it matter if the id column is not the 1st one?

Comment: Not critical that it is the 1st one, but if possible it would be nice.
The auto-increment is critical. Also would like to backfill existing rows.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `add_primary_key` instead of `add_column`?

Comment: add_primary_key makes an existing column a primary_key. I would like to add a new column that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
DB.add_column :myTable, :id, Bignum, null: false, unique: true, :auto_increment=>true
```

Note that that doesn't give you `FIRST`. If you want `FIRST`, you'll have to use raw SQL:

```
DB.run "ALTER TABLE `myTable` ADD COLUMN `id` INT AUTO_INCREMENT UNIQUE FIRST"
```

The other difference is your SQL doesn't specify `NOT NULL`, but your Sequel code does.